# Initialize all-true boolean index for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I find myself sometimes building a boolean/mask iteratively, so something like:

```py
mask = initialize_mask_to_true()
for condition in conditions:
  mask = mask & condition

df_masked = pd.loc[mask, my_cols]
```

Where conditions might be a list of separate boolean masks or comparisons like `df[some_col] > someVal`
Is there a good way to do the initialize_mask_to_true()?  Sometimes I'll do something that feels ugly like:

```py
mask = ~(df.loc[:, df.columns[0]] == np.nan)
```

which works because `something == np.nan` will always be false, but it feels like there's a cleaner way.

Comment: `mask = np.ones(your_size_here).astype(bool)`.

Comment: some_new_condition is what?

Comment: I think you could use something like `mask = np.logical_and.reduce(your_list_of_masks)`

Comment: Also the result will broadcast, so you could even just do `mask=True` then `mask & BooleanSeries` returns a `Series`

Comment: @DanielMesejo some_new_condition just meaning some sort of comparison, like `df[a_col] > some_value`

Comment: And you have `n` of those? I think this is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you can solve your issue in another way

Comment: Refactored question code to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the index must be preserved:

```
mask= pd.DataFrame(True,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
```

or

```
mask= pd.DataFrame(True,index=df.index,columns=[df.columns[0]])
```

Comment: Nice.  Or I think, even cleaner for the second example: `mask = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)`?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, if you don't need the column name.

Answer (score 7):

I use [numpy.ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) for that:

```
np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)
```